# Breaking to a new line with inline-block

Tags: css

I've run into some layout overlap issues with a css `float` container recently, and had started looking at using `display: inline-block` instead. So far, so good... except I need to be able to add line-breaks, as `clear` does for floats. Some sample text...

```css
.ib {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
}
.block-start {
  border: 1px solid #0cc;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="block-start">block-start</div>
      <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
      <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
      <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
      <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
      <div class="block-start">block-start</div>
      <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
      <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
      <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
      <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to have my `.block-start` `<div>` elements start a new line?

**EDIT**: I should mention that each `.block-start` element needs to be inline with the other `ib` blocks, like a chapter number.

Comment: chnage display css property `display: table;`

Comment: I would wrap each set of `inline-block` elements in a `block` parent element.

Comment: @sean - yeah, I might fall back on that. I was hoping for a css only solution, though.

Comment: you could try : `.block-start {  margin-left:100vw;
  transform:translate(-100vw);}` but that would have some sides effects on the block itself ,...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One hacky idea is to add a new line using pseudo element and make the element `inline` so that the line-break will affect the `inline-block` elements. The drawback is that you will not be able to style an `inline` element like you do with an `inline-block` one

```css
.ib {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
}

.block-start {
  display: inline;
  padding: 3px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
/* Create the break line */
.block-start:not(:first-child):before {
  content: "\A";
}

/* to rectify the position of the first one*/
.block-start:first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block-start">block-start</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="block-start">block-start</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="block-start">block-start</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
</div>
```

To keep the styling (the border in this case) we can consider more hacks:

```css
.ib {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
}

.block-start {
  display: inline;
  padding: 3px 3px 4px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
/* Create the break line */
.block-start:not(:first-child):before {
  content: "\A";
}

/* to rectify the position of the first one*/
.block-start:first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.block-start:not(:first-child) {
  border:1px solid transparent;
  border-right-color:red; /*the right is not an issue*/
  background:
    linear-gradient(red,red) top    right   / calc(100% - 3px) 1px,
    linear-gradient(red,red) bottom right   / calc(100% - 3px) 1px,
    linear-gradient(red,red) left 4px top 0 / 1px 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;  
  background-origin:border-box;
  padding-right:4px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block-start">block-start</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="block-start">block-start</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="block-start">block-start</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
</div>
```

As we can see, the `padding-left` is the issue here since it's applied to the pseudo element creating the line break. One idea to fix this is to consider [`box-decoration-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-decoration-break) but we will have a small drawback at the end of each line:

```css
.ib {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
}

.block-start {
  display: inline;
  padding: 3px 3px 4px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  box-decoration-break: clone; 
  border:1px solid red;
}
/* Create the break line */
.block-start:not(:first-child):before {
  content: "\A";
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block-start">block-start</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="block-start">block-start</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="block-start">block-start</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
</div>
```

We can still fix this by adding some negative margin in order to hide it behind the other elements (we should also add background color)

```css
.ib {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  background:#fff;
  position:relative;
}

.block-start {
  display: inline;
  padding: 3px 3px 4px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  box-decoration-break: clone; 
  border:1px solid red;
  
  margin-left:-15px;
  
}
.container {
  padding-left:15px;
}
/* Create the break line */
.block-start:not(:first-child):before {
  content: "\A";
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block-start">block-start</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="block-start">block-start</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="block-start">block-start</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
</div>
```

We can also consider the other pseudo element and data-attribute to have more control over the styling wihout any hacks. **This is the solution I recommend**

I have used the `class` attribute but you can consider a custom one in case you want a different content.

```css
.ib {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
}

.block-start {
  display: inline;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

/* Create the break line */
.block-start:not(:first-child):before {
  content: "\A";
}

.block-start:after {
  content: attr(class);
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid red;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block-start"></div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="block-start"></div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="block-start"></div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
</div>
```

[image: CSS break line with inline-block]

---

The same trick can also work if you want to *clear* after

```css
.ib {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
}

.block-end {
  display: inline;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  
}

/* Create the break line */
.block-end:not(:first-child):after {
  content: "\A";
}

.block-end:before {
  content: attr(class);
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="block-end"></div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="block-end"></div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="block-end"></div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
</div>
```

[image: multiline inline-block css]

---

Here is some variation of the same idea that can be useful in other situation

With flexbox:

```css
.container {
 display:flex;
 flex-wrap:wrap;
 align-items:center;
}

.ib {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 3px;
  background:#fff;
  position:relative;
  margin:0 3px 0;
}
.ib + .ib {
   margin-left:0;
}

.block-start {
  display: contents;
  
}
.container {
  padding-left:15px;
}
/* Create the break line */
.block-start:not(:first-child):before {
  content: "";
  flex-basis:100%;
  height:1px;
}
/* Will replace the content*/
.block-start:after {
  content: attr(class);
  border:1px solid red;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block-start"></div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="block-start"></div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="block-start"></div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
</div>
```

With CSS grid:

```css
.container {
 display:grid;
 grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fill,minmax(90px,1fr));
 grid-gap:2px;
 align-items:center;
}

.ib {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 3px;
  background:#fff;
  position:relative;
}

.block-start {
  display: contents;
  
}
.container {
  padding-left:15px;
}
/* Create the break line */
.block-start:not(:first-child):before {
  content: "";
  grid-column:1/-1;
}
/* Will replace the content*/
.block-start:after {
  content: attr(class);
  border:1px solid red;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block-start"></div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="block-start"></div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="block-start"></div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
</div>
```

Another one with CSS grid:

```css
.container {
 display:grid;
 grid-template-columns:repeat(10000,max-content);
 grid-gap:2px;
 align-items:center;
}

.ib {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 3px;
  background:#fff;
  position:relative;
}

.container {
  padding-left:15px;
}
/* Create the break line */
.block-start {
  grid-column:1;
  border:1px solid red;
  padding: 3px;
}
/* Will replace the content*/
.block-start:after {
  content: attr(class);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block-start"></div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="block-start"></div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="block-start"></div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
  <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Question, What's the `\A` is for ?

Comment: This comes the closest to reproducing the `clear: right;` behavior of floats -- although it doesn't _quite_ allow full styling control of the element, it's pretty close. Awesome work!

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing sounds like a Run-In Layout:

> A run-in box is a box that merges into a block that comes after it, inserting itself at the beginning of that block’s inline-level content. This is useful for formatting compact headlines, definitions, and other similar things, where the appropriate DOM structure is to have a headline preceding the following prose, but the desired display is an inline headline laying out with the text. [1]

However, browser support is currently very poor and, in some cases, has regressed[2]. If you have control over the mark-up, wrapping each group of `.ib` and `.block-start` elements in a new block-level tag is probably your best bet.

[1] https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display/#run-in-layout

[2] https://caniuse.com/#feat=run-in

Answer (score -2):

In `.block-start` selector simply change `display:inline-block` property to `display:block`. And also change the html `<div>` as shown below

I hope this will work.

```css
.ib {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
}
.block-start {
  border: 1px solid #0cc;
  display: block;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="block-start">block-start
          <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
          <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
          <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
          <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
   </div>
   <div class="block-start">block-start
          <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
          <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
          <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
          <div class="ib">inline-block</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you run your snippet, you'll see that the elements with `display: block;` consume the full of their line, and its associated elements start only in the next line.